# How can I set particles to multiple Instance Objects?

Tags: mesh, particles

[image: donut particles]

I am following the beginners donut tutorial where Andrew creates sprinkles. I did everything as explained, but there is just one sort of sprinkle. Is there an easy way to add more Instance Objects?

Comment: you can choose a collection as particle instead of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot with additional numbers]

Your problem is that you've set the hair to render as a single object and selected a single object to use.  If you want to use multiple objects from a collection, change:

1. Render -> *Render as* from `Object` to collection

[image: Render As setting showing collection selected]

2. That will add a new *Collection* subpanel to the *Render Panel*.  In that panel set *Instance Collection* to the name of the collection containing your sprinkles:

[image: Instance Collection setting showing Sprinkles being selected]